# Bijection between sets of functions (proper subset)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

How can I construct a bijection between two sets of functions $\mathcal{F}(Im;\space Y) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(X;\space Y)$, with $X$ and $Y$ finite such that $X \subsetneq Im$?

Notation: $Im = \left\{ {p \in \mathbb{N}};\space p \leqslant m \right\}  $ and
$\mathcal{F}(X;\space Y) = $ set of all functions $f: X \rightarrow Y$

Comment: Does it follow directly from the set of functions F(X;Y) being also finite?

Comment: As you stated it (or, at least, as I understood it), you cannot because there exists no bijection between the set of functions $Im\to Y$ to the set of functions $X\to Y$ unless $X=Im$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly then $\mathrm{Im}$ is an arbitrary subset of $X$. Because $\mathrm{Im}$, $X$ and $Y$ are then all finite we have
$$
 |F(\mathrm{Im},Y)| = |Y|^{|\mathrm{Im}|}
 \quad\text{and}\quad
 |F(X,Y)| = |Y|^{|X|}.
$$

If $X = \mathrm{Im}$ then already $F(\mathrm{Im},Y) = F(X,Y)$.

IF $X \neq \mathrm{Im}$ then $\mathrm{Im} \subsetneq X$ and thus $|\mathrm{Im}| < |X|$ because $X$ is finite. For $|Y|^{|\mathrm{Im}|} = |Y|^{|X|}$ we then need that $|Y| = 1$ or $|Y| = 0$.

If $|Y| = 1$ then $|F(\mathrm{Im},Y)| = |F(X,Y)| = 1$, as both sets contain only the constant function, so the only map $F(\mathrm{Im},Y) \to F(X,Y)$ is a bijection.

If $|Y| = 0$ then $Y = \emptyset$. Because $\mathrm{Im} \subsetneq X$ we have $X \neq \emptyset$ and therefore $F(X,Y) = \emptyset$. For a bijection $F(\mathrm{Im},Y) \to F(X,Y)$ to exists we need $F(\mathrm{Im},Y) = \emptyset$, which is now equivalent to $\mathrm{Im} \neq \emptyset$. In this case $F(\mathrm{Im},Y) = \emptyset = F(X,Y)$.

Comment: Im is the set of the natural numbers that are less or equal to m. So it has cardinality equal to m.

Comment: I was proving that if the cardinality of X equals m and the cardinality of Y equals n, then F(X;Y) = n^m. I managed to prove it by induction and was trying to prove it in another way; so I put X = Im. Without assuming the cardinality of Im (supposing an arbitrary subset of X), if there is a bijection between F(Im;Y) and F(X;Y), then those sets have the same cardinality. This proves it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $Y\ne\emptyset$ and $Im \subsetneqq X$, you can't, by a simple cardinality argument:
$$
\lvert F(Im; Y)\rvert = \lvert Y\rvert ^{\lvert Im\rvert}\tag{1}
$$
and similarly
$$
\lvert F(X; Y)\rvert = \lvert Y\rvert ^{\lvert X\rvert}.\tag{2}
$$
If $X$ is finite, then $Im \subsetneqq X$ implies $\lvert Im\rvert < \lvert X\rvert$, so if $Y\ne\emptyset$ then (1) is strictly less than (2).

You can construct an injection but not a bijection.